# c# EntityFramework best way to filter Active rows in queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

Trying to understand what is the best way to handle inactive records in the code
i have an Entity with DeletedDate property,

```
    public class Invitation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string InvitedByUserId { get; set; }
  
        ...
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
        
    }
```

i want to filter the ones that their deleted date is not null,

```
Invitation invitation = await db.Invitations
  .Where(invite => !invite.DeletedDate.HasValue 
&& invite.InvitedUserId == data.MemberId && 
groupMembers.Contains(invite.InvitedByUserId))
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

i tried to add to the class the function and call it from the code

```
    public class Invitation
    {
        ...
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive => !DeletedDate.HasValue;
    }

    Invitation invitation = await db.Invitations
                    .Where(invite => invite.IsActive && 
invite.InvitedUserId == data.MemberId && 
groupMembers.Contains(invite.InvitedByUserId))
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

but if failes on runtime unless i use it with :

```
Invitation invitation = await db.Invitations
 .AsAsyncEnumerable()
 .Where(invite => invite.IsActive && 
invite.InvitedUserId == data.MemberId && 
groupMembers.Contains(invite.InvitedByUserId))
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

what is the best practice to filter the deleted date easily, is AsAsyncEnumerable recommended ? or does it make the query loading time longer ?

Comment: Can you show the error? Because the first query is not a problem (!invite.DeletedDate.HasValue equivalent  [i].[DeletedDate] IS NULL)

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi - this does not return an error, but i wwas tring to figure out if there is a better way to do it, something that will be more clear since i am using it in few places in the code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that EF doesn't know how to translate `invite.IsActive` to SQL. By adding `AsAsyncEnumerable()` you are doing the evaluation in memory on the client side. Use a simple null check for `DeletedDate`.

```
Invitation invitation = await db.Invitations
    .Where(invite => invite.DeletedDate == null && invite.InvitedUserId == data.MemberId && groupMembers.Contains(invite.InvitedByUserId))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

You might also find [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) useful.

Comment: i used your recommendation about Global Query Filters useful

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Global Query Filters :
i added to the Framework Entities class - > OnModelCreating the filtering of deleted records

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Invitation>()
            .HasQueryFilter(invitation => invitation.DeletedDate == null);
    }
```

this way I can use the table and get already filtered values - only active records:

```
Invitation invitation = await db.Invitations
    .Where(invite => invite.InvitedUserId == data.MemberId && groupMembers.Contains(invite.InvitedByUserId))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```